# Java LinkedList contains() seems to fail

Tags: java, list, api

I'm trying to make a LinkedList containing the "best of" of an offspring in an evolutionary algorithm.

Therefore, I have my own custom add() method:

```
public boolean add(Virus v) {
    if((this.size()< ConfigObject.getInstance().surviverPopulation  //if the size of the new population is < surviverPopulation
            || v.getFitness() > this.getLast().getFitness())        //or the fitness is higher than that of the last member
            && v.getFitness() > 0.0                                 //and the fitness is higher than 0
            && !v.isDead()                                          //and the virus is alive
            && !this.contains((Virus)v)) {                          //and it is not yet in the list
        super.add(v);                                               //add it normally
        Collections.sort(this, new Comparator<Virus>() {            //sort the list
            //define parameter to sort by
            @Override
            public int compare(Virus virus1, Virus virus2) {        //with custom comparator
                if(virus1.getFitness() == virus2.getFitness()) {
                    return 0;
                } else if (virus1.getFitness() > virus2.getFitness()) {
                    return -1;
                } else {
                    return 1;
                }
            }
           });
    }
    while(this.size() > 300) {
        this.removeLast();
    }
    return true;
}
```

With this method, I get a LinkedList of limited size which is also sorted and only contains the "best" objects. (The rest of the LinkedList-class is unaltered).

However, when I use this class, something strange happens:

```
for(Virus parent : this.currentPopulation) {                                //for every virus in the current population
        for(GraphNode child : parent.getChildren()){                            //get all the children, and for each child
            temp = (Virus) child;   
            if(!temp.isDead() && !newCurrentPopulation.contains(child)) {       //try to add the child if it's not dead 
                newCurrentPopulation.add((Virus) child);                        //and not already in the list
            }                                                                   //(list only takes a maximum of <surviverPopulation>
        }                                                                       //and only the strongest ones, see declaration)
        newCurrentPopulation.add(parent);                                       //also try to add the parent to the list if
    }                                                                           //still alive

    int j = 0;
    for(Virus parent : this.currentPopulation) {                                //for every virus and its children in the current population
        for(GraphNode child : parent.getChildren()){                            //check if it made it into the new population
            if(!newCurrentPopulation.contains((Virus) child)) {
                toRemove.add((Virus) child);                                    //if not, memorize to delete it later
            }
        }
        if(!(newCurrentPopulation.contains((Virus) parent))); {
            toRemove.add(parent);                                               //do the same for the parent virus
        }
    }
```

It works quite fine for the children, but not for the parent. The debugging info shows that even though the parent (identifiable by an id) is in the newCurrentPopulation, it will be included into the toRemove list (where it's also identifiable by the same id).

Also, I did not override the equals-method for the Virus-class or any of its superclasses. I'm probably missing something quite obvious here but I can't see it.

Comment: If you need two instances of `Virus` to be considered equal for the purposes of `List.contains`, then you need to override `equals` in `Virus`.

Comment: @khelwood "The equals method for class Object implements the most discriminating possible equivalence relation on objects; that is, for any non-null reference values x and y, this method returns true if and only if x and y refer to the same object (x == y has the value true)."

Comment: @ Saftkeks Yes? that doesn't contradict my comment

Comment: @khelwood I only want references to the same instance to be considered "equal", not instances holding the same variables. The problem was that it seemed that a list containing the instance x would return false if I called list.contains(x). However, as I described in the answers, that was not the issue. Thanks for your time.

Comment: Next time, post a [mcve] so we don't have to guess.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is something extremely obvious indeed: the last if-statement is followed by a semicolon and not the {}.

Answer (score 0):

The `contains` method internally calls the `equals` method of `Virus` class.
The default equals method provided by the Object class uses `==` operator, which in your case returns false. 
You have to override the `equals` method in `Virus` class and compare the objects with `id`.

Comment: I'm sorry that I phrased that wrong: I'm working in Eclipse, where in the debugging section you can identify objects by ids that Eclipse (or the JVM?) assigns to them at runtime - so the same instance has the same id, but instances that look the same still have different ones. My objects don't have a field called id.